# Is it possible to prepare a solution of hydrogen sulfate in a lab? What is the procedure to do so?

Tags: acid-base, solutions

I don't want a buffer solution with it, I want to know if its possible to have a solution with only $\ce{HSO4^{-}}$ ions in it.

Comment: Well, you'll at least need a cation to maintain charge balance. Also it will be in some equilibrium with sulfate.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare such a solution by dissolving a soluble hydrogen sulfate such as [sodium hydrogen sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bisulfate) in water.

However, since the hydrogen sulfate anion is acidic, there will always be some amount of sulfate ions in the sulution. You can calculate the proportion from its dissociation constant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to prepare a $\ce{HSO4-}$ solution? Let's take the sodium salt as example.

One method involves mixing stoichiometric quantities of sodium hydroxide and sulfuric acid which react to form sodium bisulfate and water.

$$\ce{NaOH + H2SO4 → NaHSO4 + H2O}$$

Note, the reaction is exothermic. Also, as mentioned by @airhuff and @aventurin, the solution would contain some amount of sulfate ions in the solution which are in equilibrium.

Second method is to retrieve as a byproduct from the reaction of excess sulfuric acid with any of the sodium salts ($\ce{X- = CN−, NO3−, ClO4−}$):

$$\ce{NaX + H2SO4 → NaHSO4 + HX}$$

The advantage of this process is that **the acids produced have a lower boiling point than the reactants and are separated from the reaction mixture by distillation.** However I would not recommend using cyanide or perchlorate as sodium cyanide is a potent poison and perchlorate is strong oxidizer. **Do not attempt these reaction if you are not an experienced chemist.**

You can also try making it from sodium chloride. You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-GACnKVclY).

$$\ce{NaCl + H2SO4 → NaHSO4 + HCl}$$